# Project Is Not Compatible with MonoAndroid 81

Tags: android, c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Estaba programando y de pronto surgió este error:

> Project is not compatible with
>   monoandroid81(MonoAndroid,Version=v8.1). Project TaskX.iOS supports:
>   xamarinios10 (Xamarin.iOS,Version=v1.0)

La verdad, no sé a que pueda referirse, ¿Alguien tiene alguna solución?